# Display fields only once (Views)

Tags: 7, views

I would like to show a table of products. I grouped them by nid. In the table header views shows me the nid. Instead of this, I would like to add fields of the node to be displayed once like: node title, image, price.

I attached two illustrations:
Screenshot 1: This is what Views shows me.
[image: snap1]

Screenshot 2: This is what I would like to have

[image: snap2]

Answer (score 2):

You can use attachment for this. In Views UI push add and choose attachment. Add the fields as you want them to be displayed. Also look under Attachment settings in the attachment display, choose which view to attach to, before / after etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the fields you want "Product name, Dimensions, List price".
2. Click on Settings from your view FORMAT section in settings page.
3. Chose group items from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different block display for just the first element, with a limit of 1, and add it as a header of the view page (the view you currently have). Also, to not output the first element twice, add an offset of 1 in the view page.

And add any additional fields you want in the block display.